# Series expansion for irrational functions such as $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

So far I have been able to expand most rational and transcendental functions into the Maclaurin series. But irrational functions such as this one $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}}$ confuse me. I try to use the binomial series formula but the general formula only gives me $2$ terms. What I have tried to do is to set up a dummy variable $X=x+x^2$ so that my function has the form $(1+X)^\frac{1}{2}$ and expand them, then reinsert the variable into the expression.

Is this method correct or not? Is there a more general binomial series formula to deal with non-factorable irrational expression?

Comment: That should work. The key point is that power series about a point are unique if they exist. So if you find one power series that converges to the desired expression, it is *the* power series.

Comment: Take a look at the generating function of $P_n(-1/2)$ with $P_n(x)$ being the $n$th Legendre polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

As $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2),$

$$(1+x+x^2)^{-1/2}=(1-x)^{1/2}(1-x^3)^{-1/2}$$

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series assuming $|x|<1$

Comment: How do you factor so fast that expression?

Comment: @James, Please find the updated version

Comment: What will happen if the generating function is irrational and is not factorable?

Comment: @JamesWarthington (1) People have the factorization of $A^3-B^3$ memorized. It's also a special case of the (homogeneous version) of the geometric sum formula, which gives a factorization of $A^n-B^n$ for general $n$, as well as $A^n+B^n$ for odd $n$. (2) All polynomials are factorizable with complex numbers. What kind of functions are you talking about otherwise? Be specific what you mean by "irrational" function - is it just an expression built from rational expressions and taking radicals? There may be no general answer better than "do it piece by piece" it's so broad.

Answer (score 1):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and related properties of the partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}\,}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k \frac1{(1+x+x^2)^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}(1+2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&\to\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k B_{n,k}(1,2,0,\dotsc,0), \quad x\to0\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k} 2^kB_{n,k}\biggl(\frac12,1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k(2k-1)!! \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}\frac1{2^{2k-n}}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \binom{k}{n-k},
\end{align*}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation*}
\frac1{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}\,}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \binom{k}{n-k}\Biggr]x^n.
\end{equation*}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
4. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.